# Efficient search algorithm for determining which sets are a subset of a larger set

Tags: performance, search

Consider a collection of sets `A1`, `A2`,...,`An`. I want to determine the most efficient algorithm for finding which of these sets are subsets of a different set `B`.

For example, let the input of the algorithm be:

```
A1 = [1 2]
A2 = [2 3 4]
A3 = [1 3]
B = [1 2 3]
```

The algorithm should return:

```
output = [1 3]
```

since `A1` and `A3` are subsets of `B` but `A2` is not.

Comment: If you want any clever optimizations, you'll have to put this operation in context. On its own, there's not much you can do. Sorting or building a hash table from `B` and then running the corresponding standard containment tests is all you can do.

Comment: @user2357112 Hi, thank you for the comment. To give a little more context: the set B contains a selection of integers (without duplicates) from the set 1 to about 1000 or 10000. There are many sets A, on the order of 1000, which only contain anywhere from 1 to 3 integers (again without duplicates) from the same set (1 to 1000 or 10000).

Answer (score 2):

The simple O(N) answer: Start with both lists sorted. Pick the shorter list, and for each entry, check if it's present on the other side. You don't need to do a fancy search of the other list, just keep a pointer and increment until we find or pass our target number.

On the other hand, you can still speed up "O(N)" operations by making each step simpler for the computer. For example, if you only need a count of how many numbers are in common, you can compute that quite quickly with a [bitmask](http://blog.getspool.com/2011/11/29/fast-easy-realtime-metrics-using-redis-bitmaps/)

If you are comparing many lists to one special list, and most numbers will NOT be in common, you can create a [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). This can tell you "number X is NOT in set Y" very quickly. It can't tell you if the number is present -- you'll have to double-check that manually. This is a speed win if you think MOST numbers are misses, and only a few will be hits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have a couple of questions: 1) for the bitmask approach, if I know that `A1 = [1 2]` and `B = [1 2 3]` and the operation tells me that there are two elements in common, I know that `A1` must be in `B` because there are only two elements in `A1`. Similarly, say `B = [1 3]` then there is only one element in common and `A1` is not a subset of `B`. So, in summary, can I check subsets by simply comparing the numbers in common? I.E. the number of elements in common (between `A1` and `B`) is less than the number of elements in `A1` if and only if `A1` is not a subset of `B`?

Comment: 2) To generalize the quoted text to "set X is not in set Y," do I have to test all numbers in X in order to determine if X is a subset of Y? I'm not sure how this would help in efficiency over just comparing the two lists directly.

Comment: Only you know your data well enough to know which short-cuts will be valuable. For example, you could ask "Is the biggest element in A less than the smallest element in B"?  If your data overlaps a lot, that would be a waste, since that would rarely skip work. But if you notice that your data rarely overlaps, then it might be a win.